# Find node with lowest numeric value in array

Tags: php

I have this following array output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 32.4 km )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 10.2 km )
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 205 km )
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 50.8 km ) 
)
```

I am trying to get the shortest distance from a particular address and from this result the shortest is 10.2 km. How can I compare all the km distance and just display the one with the smallest number?

My main goal here is the get the shortest distance based on this array result.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the numeric values from your array using [`floatval()`](http://php.net/floatval) and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), then use [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) to find the lowest value in the array:

```
echo min(array_map('floatval', $array));
```

Demonstration: http://codepad.org/LRNig19H

Answer (score 1):

```
$min_distance = $array[0][0];

foreach($array as $distance)
  $min_distance = (filter_var($distance[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT) < filter_var($min_distance, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) ? $distance[0] : $min_distance;

echo $min_distance;
```

Since I don't know what you array is called I used `$array`. I hope that helps you!

A little explanation on the methods I used.

`foreach` runs through every element of a array. The current node will be safed in the variable after `as`.

`filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)` is making a number out of string, that is not completely a made out of digits. Means `"23.5 km"` converts into `23.5`.

`(boolean) ? value1 : value2` is just a short if statement. If `boolean` is true the expression eqauls `value1`, if not `value2`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: `intval()` will cut "32.4 km" to "32" which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-use the whole `SimpleXMLElement` that contains the lowest distance value and not just print the distance (assumed the object contains more data than just the distance), you can adjust this snippet to your needs:

```
$lowest_item = NULL; 
$lowest_value = NULL;
// iterate over all SimpleXMLElements as a reference for later re-use
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    // extract number from string -- adjust $item[0] to the real object property
    $numeric_value = floatval($item[0]);
    // check if current item is lower than one of the previous
    if ($lowest_value == NULL || $lowest_value >= $numeric_value) {
        $lowest_item = $item;
        $lowest_value = $numeric_value;
    }
}
var_dump($lowest_item);
```